# Accessing data from CakePHP's find() return array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Here's an example of an array that is returned by CakePHP's [find()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) method:

```
Array 
(
    [Tutor] => Array 
    ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [PersonaId] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

The official documentation shows how to fetch records, but does not show how to iterate through them or even read out a single value. I'm kind of lost at this point. I'm trying to fetch the `[id]` value within the array. Here's what I've tried:

```
// $tutor is the array.
print_r($tutor[0]->id);
```

> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 0
>   [APP\Controller\PersonasController.php, line 43]
>
> Notice (8): Trying to
>   get property of non-object [APP\Controller\PersonasController.php,
>   line 43]

I've also tried:

```
// $tutor is the array.
print_r($tutor->id);
```

> Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP\Controller\PersonasController.php, line 44]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->` way of accessing properties is used in objects. What you have shown us is an array. In that example, accessing the id would require

```
$tutor['Tutor']['id']
```

Official PHP documentation, "[Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)":

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
         "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);

var_dump($array["foo"]); //"bar"
var_dump($array[42]); //24
var_dump($array["multi"]["dimensional"]["array"]); //"foo"
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. I went ahead and added some official PHP documentation and examples to further explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is an array, not an object. This should work:

```
echo $tutor['Tutor']['id'];
```

Or:

```
foreach($tutor as $tut){
    echo $tut['Tutor']['id'] . '<br />';
}
```